# Passing variable value to inner class method

Tags: java

I have a method with an inner method, and an index value, that I'd like to pass, to the inner method.

The method:

```
public CharSequence encodeSmileyChars(String index_str){
    CharSequence cs;

    // The value I'd like to pass...
    int index = Integer.parseInt(index_str); 

    ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                                                     // ...here˘ 
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(images[index]);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return d;
        }
    };

    cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src='"
                    + getResources().getDrawable(images[index])
                    + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
    return cs;
}
```

Can someone, please tell me if this is possible and how this could be accomplished?

Comment: You can do this, but you have to declare `index` as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use `index` inside this method that would work because that's still the scope where `index` exist. You do just need to add the `final` modifier to it in order to do so.